# Find ASIdentifierManager API usage in pre-compiled library

Tags: ios, iphone

Apple rejected game with below message.

```
We found your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, section 3.3.12 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement states:

"You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier, and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine, correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly, the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the reset Advertising Identifier."

Please check your code - including any third-party libraries - to remove any instances of:

class: ASIdentifierManager
selector: advertisingIdentifier
framework: AdSupport.framework

If you are planning to incorporate ads in a future version, please remove the Advertising Identifier from your app until you have included ad functionality.

To help locate the Advertising Identifier, use the “nm” tool. For information on the “nm” tool, open a terminal window and enter, “man nm.”

If you do not have access to the libraries source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using the "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool lists the methods that the library calls, and "otool -ov" will list the Objective-C class structures and their defined methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the problematic code resides.
```

In my system, otool and nm command not found, Is there any other way to find ASIdentifierManager?
Now apple not allow if we link adsupport framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have integrate with Facebook or Google Analytics? Those Frameworks use AdSupport.Framework.

For Google Analytics, you need update the framework and add "-force_load\ GoogleAnalyticsServices" in Build Settings > Other linker flags.

For the Facebook SDK, get FBUtility.m from (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) and replace the `+ (NSString *)advertiserID`  method with the code below:

```
 + (NSString *)advertiserID {
    return @"";
 }
```